# Convert Spring MVC template to GAE

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Anyone have some template to Transform spring MVC template to run on GAE ?
I already tried different aproaches without success.
Last thing I tried was to add GAE dependency and plugin and criate appengine-web.xml file...

I allways get the message "this project is not a google app engine project"

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.14</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.14</version>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: anyone with the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring and Google App Engine can be made to work together however the structure of a Google App Engine Java Project is very different from the standard Spring or Java Web Project.

If you want to use Maven with Google App Engine I'd suggest copying one of the example/template archetypes and adding the Spring libraries to the project. I've had much greater success with doing it this way. However I have opted not to use Maven with Google App Engine and Spring because the latest version of Spring does not play well with Google App Engine.

The easiest option is to start from a Maven Archetype that contains the key components you want. If you want to progress without Maven you can create a standard Google App Engine project in Eclipse and incorporate the Spring libraries.

Word of warning. Follow the instructions linked below else you'll end up with an application that takes a very long time to start up instances. Due to the way Spring autowires it can take a minute or more for an application to start when deployed to App Engine without correct configuration.

Best of luck!

Read More:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization